# How to select FK as header names and values as a list of these values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following structure:

```
TABLE: Field
ID |  Name  
---|--------
 1 |  Email
 2 |  City
```

And

```
TABLE: Answers
ID |  Field  | Value        |  User
-----------------------------------
 1 |    1    | m1@mail.com  |   3
 2 |    2    | abc          |   3
 3 |    1    | m2@mail.com  |   4
 4 |    2    | qwe          |   4
```

I want to select:

```
Email       | City
-------------------
m1@mail.com | abc
m2@mail.com | qwe
```

How can I do it?

Comment: How can you tell that m1@mail.com is related to abc and m2@mail.com is related to qwe? I don't see any relationship in the given data.

Comment: @Joe I've added `User` column to simulate this...

Comment: I assume these are dynamic? Not a fixed list.

Comment: @Martin yes, the fields are dynamic. They are stored on the table `Fields`. I could have more fields and would like to select them as well. I want to select all from `Fields` as the header and the `Answers` as the values...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns + ',[' + cast(f.[Name] as varchar) + ']',
'[' + CAST(f.[Name] as VARCHAR)+ ']')
FROM Answers AS a INNER JOIN Field AS f ON a.[Field] = f.[ID]
GROUP BY f.[Name]

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @query = '
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT f.[Name], a.[Value], a.[User]
FROM Answers AS a INNER JOIN Field AS f ON a.[Field]
= f.[ID]) AS s
PIVOT (MAX(Value) FOR [Name] IN (' + @columns + ')) AS p'

EXECUTE(@query);
```

Comment: BTW - You should use `quote_name` rather than concatenating the square brackets yourself to deal correctly with any field names that happen to contain the `]` character.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  User, 
MAX(CASE WHEN field=1 THEN value END) AS [Email],  
MAX(CASE WHEN field=2 THEN value END) as [City]
FROM test
GROUP BY  User;
```

You can also do the same using `PIVOT`, but personally I found the syntax above clearer and easier to use than `PIVOT`. If you have dynamic fields, you need to make this query generic also. I'd assume creating function that analyzes all distinct values in in the first table, iterates through them, and returns a proper query ( You need to append `MAX(CASE WHEN field=N THEN value END) AS [Field_N_Name]` for each `ID` in the first table

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you can do that in a single select statement.

It's a little confusing, but I think this could work:

```
SELECT
    External.Value as Email, 
    City 
FROM
    Answers as External
JOIN
(
    SELECT
        Answers.Value as City,
        Answers.User
    FROM
        Answers
    WHERE
        Answers.Field = 2 
) AS Internal
ON
(External.User = Internal.User)
WHERE 
    External.Field = 1
```

Since the column is the same, I'm first selecting the email and then selecting the city, and finally joining them both so they appear in the same result row.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A1.Value, A2.Value FROM Answers A1 JOIN Answers A2 on A1.User = A2.User
```

"Self-join". But this is a non-generic solution that will break when you add Field 3.